# Ruby class associations

Tags: ruby, oop, associations

I'm having trouble creating a class association in Ruby, since it's a dynamic typed language. In Java, I write like this:

```
public class Foo {
   ...
}

public class Bar {
   public Foo foo;
   ...
}
```

How can I write something similar in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo

end

class Bar

  attr_accessor :foo

  def initialize (foo)
    @foo = foo
  end

end

foo = Foo.new
bar = Bar.new(foo)

puts bar.foo
```

For what you say, seems you need some kind of *type safety*. You can achieve something like that by doing

```
def initialize (foo)
  raise ArgumentError, "You must provide a valid Foo instance" unless foo.instace_of?(Foo)
  @foo = foo
end
```

Comment: I wasn't much clear. I want to pass an existing Foo object to Bar.

Comment: I believe that you want to pass it in the constructor? edited

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've already thought about this solution, but seems danger to me since I could pass a wrong variable through the constructor. I guess it's the price for dynamic typing. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: There. I edited the answer to provide some type safety. Anyway in ruby it's better not to care about the types and just see if the object can respond to messages by using `respond_to?`

Comment: Hey from the future. Will this allow me to get foo.bars? or just Bar.foo?